# не получается сделать аутентификацию с файлом в СИ

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>  

main()  
{  
    FILE *p;  
char buf_login[10];  
char buf_stream[10];  
puts("Login:");  
scanf("%s",buf_login);  
printf("Your login is:%s\n", buf_login);  
p=fopen("12.txt","rt");  
fgets(buf_stream, 10, p);  
fclose(p);  
if (strcmp(buf_stream,buf_login)==0)  
    {  
    puts("OK");  
    }  
 else {  
    puts("error!");  
    }   

}
```

Не получается пройти "аутентификацию". В файле `12.txt`, к примеру, находится `abcd`. Компилирую, ввожу `abcd` и все равно выкидывает error! вместо ОК. Не могу понять, где ошибка. Вроде код правильный. Кодировка 12.тхт файла `ASCII`. Пишу в Borland 2.0, на виртуалке на Ubuntu.

Comment: Уберите картинку и вставьте нормальный исходник . Ссылка "править" под постом. И не забудьте отформатировать исходник как код (кнопка `{}` в редкторе).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибки могут быть две...

1. Если файл открывается для чтения, то в нем на самом деле не строка "abcd", а строка "abcd\n"(с переводом строки). Убрать можно открыв сам файл в режиме редактирования и при помощи клавиш перемещения курсора и удаления убрать из файла последний непечатный символ (после символа "d"). У Вас должна получиться одна строка без перевода каретки.
2. Файл не открывается, так как не находится в той же директории, откуда и запускается программа. Подтверждением открытия файла должен служить валидный указатель p. В своем коде Вы его не проверяете, но посмотрите хотя бы в отладчике. Хотя скорее всего, в случае отсутствия файла, программа вывалится с ошибкой.

Сам же код в принципе рабочий.

Comment: фаил находится  в правельной директории, значит проблема с `\n`, можете помочь?

Comment: @Artyom Olufsen Помочь убрать из файла возврат каретки? Вы серьезно? Неужели все настолько плохо? :)

Comment: помочь понять, в файле нету символа перевода строки.

Comment: создал фаил на Винде и скинул в виртуалку и всё заработало... буду разбираться с \n. Спасибо большое!

Comment: @ArtyomOlufsen, все работает. Попробуйте создать файл вот так: `echo -n abcd >12.txt` / А вообще, переходите на программирование прямо в линуксе, меньше глюков будет.

Comment: @ArtyomOlufsen, "*фаил находится в правельной директории*" - подтверждением этому может быть *только* проверка указателя `p` на неравенство `NULL`, но никак не ваши слова. "*в файле нету символа перевода строки*" - опять же, веры на слово в программировании не бывает. Покажите вывод `printf( "[%s]\n", buf_stream);`

Comment: @PinkTux, BCPP кладёт exe'шник рядом с исходником, так что там ошибиться папкой достаточно сложно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, OK. Теперь не буду проверять возврат функций, а составлю список правил "IDE/где бинарь" и буду ориентироваться только на него :) Вот только что делать, когда бинарь выпускается в большую жизнь?

Comment: @Artyom Olufsen просто посмотрите на размер файла. Он должен быть 4 байта. Если 5 байт и более - значит в файле есть еще лишние символы.

Answer (score 1):

Причина проблемы Вам уже указана - символ '\n' в конце строки в файле "12.txt".

Читаем man 3 fgets:

fgets()  reads  in  at  most  one  less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into  the buffer.  A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in the buffer.

Т.е. у Вас в буфере лежит последовательность символов "abcd", после которой лежит символ '\n' и только ПОСЛЕ него уже находится терминатор строки '\0'.

А когда Вы считываете логин с клавиатуры с помощью scanf, там символ '\n' в буфер НЕ попадает, поэтому и сравнение не срабатывает - строки разной длины!.

Этот лишний символ '\n' легко убрать так:

```
 buf_stream[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';
```

Т.е. просто замазываем ненужный символ '\n' терминатором строки.

И, кстати - да, проверять условие открытия файла нужно ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО!!!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте ради смеха набрать вашей программе пароль `0987654321` - она свалится из-за переполнения буфера.

Функция `scanf` с форматом `%s` небезопасна, так как размер буфера она не проверяет.

Чуть более безопасный вариант - `scanf("%9s",buf);` Обратите внимание, что массив у вас на 10 элементов, но вмещается в него 9 символов + маркер конца строки.